# Calculate area with a buffer

Tags: qgis, vector, buffer, area

I have two layers, a set of households and burned area (vector data). I created buffer zones around each household and now want to estimate the burned area within a buffer. Unfortunately "intersect" doesn't help and always gives me the error code 506 - Object (506) has invalid geometry.

[image: enter]

I am working in QGIS 3.4.

Comment: Try fixing your geometries first: search for `check validity` and `fix geometries` in the processing toolbox

Comment: Thanks, I now created a new layer through intersect. What's next? I still have different values for each pixel (day of burn) in my burned area but only want to calculate the total area burned within the buffer

Comment: "for each pixel" - sorry i am confused. I thougt you have vector data?

Comment: Yes, sorry. It is not each pixel but I don't know how to explain it properly. The layer shows different days during the year as "fields". Maybe the picture might help. I want to calculate the whole yellow area.

Answer (score 2):

You can open the attribute table of your intersection layer and create a new double or integer field and enter the expression `sum($area)`. This will sum up all areas of all features of that layer in the CRS units (so make sure your layer is projected to a metric system, then the result will be in m²).

If you want to sum the areas up by groups, use the expression `sum($area, group_by:="buffer_id")` where "buffer_id" refers to a fieldname which is unique within each buffer.

Comment: Okay I did that, but how can I know calculate the area only within one buffer. I need an output like: 5000ha/m^2 in buffer 1.

Comment: @IdaJAKOB see my edit